# OpenCV Python: FloodFill acting strange

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, flood-fill

I'm trying to **extract digit from a noisy image by using Floodfill** on the pixels **near the center**.

Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random

def floodFillCenter(img):
    mask = np.zeros([img.shape[0]+2,img.shape[1]+2],dtype=np.uint8) # Mask is totally black

    # Floodfill on random black pixels near the center
    width = img.shape[1]
    height = img.shape[0]
    floodedAreaWidth = 10
    floodedAreaHeight = 10

    numberOfTimesFlood = 20
    ignoredNumber = 0 # This value is ignored we set flags to FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY

    floodflags = 8  # Flood 8 directions
    floodflags |= cv2.FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY
    floodflags |= (255 << 8) # Fill corresponding pixels in mask with 255 (white)

    count = 0
    for row in range(height//2-floodedAreaHeight, height//2+floodedAreaHeight):
        for col in range(width//2-floodedAreaWidth, width//2+floodedAreaWidth):
            if count == numberOfTimesFlood:
                return mask
            if img[row][col] == 0:  # If we hit a black pixels in the middle, flood
                _,_,mask,_ = cv2.floodFill(img, mask, (row,col), ignoredNumber, 0, 0, floodflags)
                count += 1
                cv2.imwrite("Mask" + str(count) + ".jpg", mask)
    return mask


img = cv2.imread("8.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

_, img = cv2.threshold(img, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) # Get a binary image (0 or 255)

cv2.imwrite("AfterThreshold.jpg", img)

img = floodFillCenter(img)

cv2.imwrite("FinalMask.jpg", img)
```

I floodFill 20 times (so that at least one the pixels is part of the digit), in the hope that it would fill the whole digit and left out most of the noise.

Everything works fine for the first 13 masks:

[image: After threshold.jpg] (AfterThreshold.jpg)

[image: Mask 1->13.jpg] (Mask1->13.jpg - Same image)

However, **from Mask14.jpg, it got weird:**

[image: Mask14->20.jpg] (Mask14->20.jpg - Same image)

I need to floodFill that much number of times since I'm not always lucky (Get the whole digit right the first time). Sometimes there are noises near the center as well, and other times the digit might not be fully connected.

Can anybody please explain why this strange thing happens to me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't understand. Are you repeating this process because you're trying to find a black pixel that is part of the digit rather than noise? If so, why don't you just invert the image and find the largest connected component?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do. Thank you for suggesting that. I'm new to OpenCv and computer vision. That is a good idea. I'll do some research on that.